# From "descriptions with typos" to "labels"

Tags: label, spell-checking, text-processing, text-parsing, word-cloud

## Background

I do have an image dataset (similar to [*ImageNet*](http://www.image-net.org/)) which comes with a "description with typos" per each image. I would like to run some deep convolutional neural network on this guy, but I need to generate the "labels" first. So, here's the question:

## Question

How to generate categories' "label" from "descriptions with typos"?

## Technical information

The dataset has around 13M images with corresponding (valid) "description" and optional "typos". Some examples of "descriptions" follow below:

[image: First example] [image: Second example]

## Ideas

I was thinking to approach the problem in the following way.

1. Fix typos:

   - Run a spell check to **identify** spelling errors;
   - Find the better word that could fix it, by

     - looking at other descriptions in the dataset, or
     - checking the image and correcting the typo manually;
2. Generate the final labels:

   - run a clustering algorithm (k-means, for example) on a sentence embedding (function that maps sentences into a ℝᴺ) or
   - use the most recurrent words.

Comment: Instead of downvoting without reason, since this question **does** show "research effort", it **is** "clear" **and** "useful", would be nicer to write something to the user who asked it. Ask for further information, if something is missing, or suggesting an algorithmic solution (that is what this website is all about).

Comment: I think that the question is valid, and a good one. But it can be off-topic here. What about asking in a site lik [Computational Science SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I would say this is not OT here, but I would be tempted to say [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) would be a better fit for getting an answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. Since the nature of my question, I have carefully though about "where" to write this question, and eventually I concluded that, since it was about an "algorithmic solution", [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) was the best fit. It's not about statistical inference nor a specific numerical method. But, if experienced users believe there is a better location for this question, I gently invite them to move it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some ideas:

1. You should clearly run a spell checking, otherwise your labels will be even more noisy. Options:

   - Check a Information retrieval course and implement the checking, google lecture3-tolerant-retrieval-handout-6-per.pdf (I bet this is not the way to go) In case you want frequencies, google "Natural Language Corpus Data"
   - Use some code http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html (in many languages)
2. Regarding labeling (I guess you want it automatically otherwise there are semi automatic methods):

   - Use http://viget.com/extend/tagging-text-automatically I have never used them but it should work reasonable well
   - I would not recommend using k means because you do know the number of groups
   - Use the most recurrent word might work for few examples (like the ones you show there) but it might not work for many cases.

I hope this can be useful